Pointwise convergence on $[-n,n]$ implies uniform convergence on $\Bbb{R}$

Let $k \in \Bbb{N}$ and a collection $\{ f_n : \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^k \}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$  of continuous functions which are $0$ except maybe on $[-n,n]$ . Consider $f : \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^k, f(t) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(t) $ .

My question is, are there any conditions that can be added to $f_n$ and $f$ that gives uniform convergence? I have looked over my notes on Real analysis but all the theorems I saw in class was about a sequence defined on a set that converges uniformly to a function on the same set.
EDIT
I have edited the hypothesis in order to solve the problem of the definition of uniformly convergence.

Even uniform convergence on each $[-n, n]$ would not imply uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$. And in your situation I’m not sure what uniform convergence even means given that the functions are not defined on the entire $\mathbb{R}$.

@DavidGao Thanks for your comment. What I understund of uniform on this case is that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lVert f_n - f \rVert_{\infty} = 0$

And that is the problem right? If $f_n$ is only defined on $[-n, n]$ and $f$ is defined on the entire real line, what does the infinity norm even mean?

@DavidGao You are right. I think that more precisely, it should be described as $ \lim {n \rightarrow \infty} \sup{t \in [-n,n]} \lVert f_n(t) - f(t) \rVert $

It's not clear what it would mean to be uniformly converge on $\mathbb R$ when none of the functions in the sequence is defined on $\mathbb R.$ You could define uniform converge on and bounded interval, I suppose.

@DanielGarcía That is a reasonable definition. Then the question is what kind of conditions do you want? You could just check whether $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{t \in [-n, n]} |f_n(t) - f(t)|$ equals $0$, after all. What kind of conditions would be useful for you? Like some kind of conditions on derivatives?

@DavidGao I think that anything that work will help me, continuity of $f$, the derivability of $f_n$ or $f$. Any conditions that along with the pointwise convergence implies the uniform convergence would be okay

@DanielGarcía Well, differentiability of $f_n$ and $f$, together with $L^1$ convergence of $f’_n$ to $f’$ would work. But I guess that’s not much different from just asking for uniform convergence in the first place.

I think you might want to think a bit about how to refine your question. First, as mentioned in some of the comments on your post, it's not clear how to what you mean by uniform convergence of the $f_n$ on $\mathbb{R}$, since each is only defined on $[-n,n]$.
Supposing instead that your question is

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^k$ be continuous, and suppose that for some $f_\infty : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^k$, $f_n \to f_\infty$ pointwise, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{x \in [-n,n]} |f_n(x) - f_\infty(x)| = 0$. Then must $f_n(x)$ converge to $f_\infty(x)$ uniformly?

The answer is no. I saw in the comments that there was some discussion about whether adding differentiability hypotheses to the $f_n$ might help with this, but unfortunately the the answer there too is no. An easy counterexample with all $f_n \in C^\infty$ is as follows:
For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define
$$
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in [-n,n] \\
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1 - (|x| - n)^2}\right) & \text{if } |x| \in (n, n+1) \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Here's a Desmos plot. As you can see, as $n \to \infty$, the $f_n$ converge to the constant function $f_\infty(x) = 1$. However, for all $n$,
$$
\|f_\infty - f_n \|_{\infty} = 1,
$$
so naturally $\lim_{n\to\infty} \|f_\infty - f_n\|_\infty = 1$.
On the other hand, if you require all the $f_n$ to be analytic and maybe uniformly bounded or something of that flavor, you might be able to use something along the lines of the identity theorem to get the result.

Uhm, sorry but I already know that the answer is that it does not converges uniformly. This is why I am asking about any conditions that could be added to the pointwise convergence to imply the uniform convergence.

Right, sorry I could have communicated this more clearly, but I was showing that it's not sufficient to just put differentiability hypotheses on the $f_n$ as was being discussed in the comment thread under your original question. In particular, in my counterexample, all the $f_n$ are smooth. That's why I was suggesting you look into a condition like analyticity. Did you take a look at the link to the identity theorem?
